# HSQLDB just time value in insert

Tags: hsqldb

We are using HSQLDB for JUnits, our production database is Oracle.

I have a table in which there is a field (type is timestamp in Oracle) that carries the information about some important time in day.

I wanted to prepare test data for JUnit in script, but I failed.

The basic idea I can do in Oracle DB is

```
SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

when I tried the same with `CURRENT_TIME` in HSQLDB I got error:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
```

the next idea I got was to add time to "empty date", tried:

```
DATE '0000-01-01'
```

but got

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

strange for `DATE '2013-01-01'` it works fine, maybe the initialia zeros are the problem...no they are not, same for `DATE '0-01-01'`...

In this phase I was kind of mad already (think I can do in Oracle in a second and I spent several hours here).

From [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_datetime_functions) I tried to find some combination of functions that creates the required result, but unfortunately I found that the documentation is not clear. It seems so for first read, but when tried I was surprised why this

```
DATEADD( 'hour', 1, CURRENT_DATE )
```

works fine, while

```
DATEADD( 'hour', 1, CURRENT_TIME)
```

ends with

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
```

as opposite, DATE_ADD works for both and parameter type for both functions is the same in documentation :-/

I believe that I can do, something like

```
// 4x call of DATEADD, datetime not working as described above
date - years - months - days + seconds_from_midnight
```

but there have to be something simple to use (I hope so).

HSQLDB version: 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this setting for your tests:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```

Then this works and returns an INTERVAL

```
SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

The simpler form is `CAST (SYSDATE AS TIME)` to return the time part of SYSDATE, which you can convert to an interval.

This date `DATE '0000-01-01'` is not accepted as there is no YEAR 0. You need to use `DATE '0001-01-01'`

This works fine to convert the time of the day into an INTERVAL:

```
LOCALTIME - TIME'00:00:00'
```

Note LOCALTIME has no time zone, while CURRENT_TIME has.

Comment: Ok, setting syntax to ORA is a good workaround in this case. About the year 0 I was confused by Java, here is available to set year to 0.